# I want to take a string through console and store it in a character array

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a string to character array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
String text = "foo";
char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
```

It's not clear what this has to do with the console (as per your title). Please clarify if this isn't what you're after.

Comment: than u jon skeet .its working